# Set (border) radius of a WKInterfaceImage by code

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

I have to set the radius attribute of a `WKInterfaceImage` by Swift code.

I need the same formatting as for my others UIImageViews:

```
logoView.layer.cornerRadius = logoView.frame.width / 2
    logoView.clipsToBounds = true
    logoView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    logoView.layer.borderColor = UIColor (
                                    red: 0x33 / 255,
                                    green: 0x99 / 255,
                                    blue: 0x66 / 255,
                                    alpha: 1.0
                                ).CGColor
```

I checked the reference guide but I found no solution. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't have this type of functionality with a [WKInterfaceImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceImage). There are only a few public APIs.

In order to round the corners of an interface element in WatchKit, you need to use a WKInterfaceGroup. It allows you to modify the radius of all the corners directly in the storyboard.

[image: WKInterfaceGroup Parameters in Storyboard]

If you need to create an outlined border around the group, then you'll need to create a custom UIImage and set it as the background image of the group.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! The problem is, that I have no idea how many pixels the radius should have (calculated by code-behind source) and the `clipsToBounds` attribute is missing. :(

Comment: Well, you have a few options. You could render the image manually using Core Graphics, or you could create a few different outline images using cap insets so scale up to the appropriate size. Without knowing more about your use case, that's about as much as I can help.

Answer (score 9):

There is no direct way to do this. But I can think of a work around. The only interface object that can have a corner radius is WKInterfaceGroup. So, you can put a group inside a group and give both a corner radius. Set your image as the inner group background.

To have a border width & color, give your inner group a relative width and hight to the outer one. And give the outer a background of which you want your border color be.

Comment: That sounds logical. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

---

> Just set the Radius Property and remember group should not be nested
>   otherwise corners will not set to 0

---

[image: Just set the Radius Property and remember group should not be nested otherwise radius will not apply]